# Using DIVs inside table cells

Tags: css, html

In [this table](http://jsfiddle.net/B74zV/), not just cell B has a heading and content, but also cells A and C.

[image]

My attempt to set the heading and the content using DIVs is only partially successful. `font-weight` is observed, but `vertical-align` is not. Why?

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    td {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .heading {
        vertical-align: top;
        font-weight: bold
    }
    .content {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="300px" height="300px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">A</td>
        <td>
            <div class="heading">Heading of Cell B</div>
            <div class="content">Content of Cell B</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: verticle align should be middle

Comment: tables are for tabular data and should be used properly, if you are not going to layout your data properly then you shouldn't bother with them at all

Answer (score 1):

verticle align should be middle

```
 verticle-align: middle;
```

This will place the text in the middle. Although you have to be aware that is places it in the middle on the line (not the container) so you need a line-height

```
 line-height: xxx;
```

Or use div's and mimic a table: http://jsfiddle.net/rf2kC/

Comment: I am not trying to eliminate the table altogether. The table already has an intricate set of colspan and rowspan attributes. Inserting a heading for each cell would mean that maintaining the table would become unwieldy. Hence I am trying to style some parts as a cell heading and others as a cell content without modifying the structure of the table itself. Using DIV or anything else is fine.

Answer (score 0):

vertical align won't work on an element that is displayed in-line, like a div. you can put another table inside of your TD, or change your css to something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    td {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .heading {
            position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background: blue;
    height: 150px;
    }
    .content {
      position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background: yellow;
    height: 150px;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: here are some links to help you learn about display options: http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html & http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Trying what you suggested http://jsfiddle.net/LSvmw/ doesn't make the content centered. What am I missing?

Comment: add " text-align: center; " to both .heading and .content

Comment: I'm rather after "vertical-align: middle;". Can vertical centering be achieved by other than "vertical-align"?

Comment: you can try to give the .header and .content a display: table OR display: table-cell .  i didnt have luck getting the content to position itself as desired that way, which is why i didnt mention it. perhaps you can play around with it and get it to work though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   td {
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align:top;

    }

    .heading {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .content {
        margin: auto;
        line-height: 200px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xvx83/

Comment: Setting line-height to some large value doesn't help if I have actual content to write in the cell! http://jsfiddle.net/9Qs5u/